# how can i use the postgresql's Geometric Types

Tags: postgresql

How can i implement Geometric Types in postgresql db..
Postgresql db is hosted in windows os.. and how can i get whether point is in circle or not?
getting errors when i am using predefined functions...
Is there anything do i need to install further .. i am using postgresql 9.1 version. I have seen PostGIS for Linux... what is that .. how can will it be useful?

Thanks in advance
Aj..

Comment: Have you installed PostGIS into your PostgreSQL install?

Comment: do we have to install postgis for working with geometric types?
if i install postgis .. wher do i create the new database.. is it in postgis or postgresql??

Comment: ahh no never mind

Comment: Can you clarify if you need geometric or geometry.  This is the help for the geometric http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-geometry.html

Comment: i need to work on vehicle tracking system... i guess i need both...

Comment: geometry is your best bet.  You will need to install PostGIS

Comment: can i install the postGIS in winwods server?

Comment: Yes, you can use it on Windows.

Comment: is there any demo link or examples how to do vehicle tracking system using postGIS and PHP?

Comment: That is a different question, please ask a new one on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install PostGIS.  Postgresql doesn't come with geometry types out of the box, PostGIS defines geometry and geography types, and gives you the functions needed to interact with your spatial data.

Comment: i need to work on vehicle tracking system... how postgresql wil fit to my needs and can i use postGIS/ArcGIS in windows server?

Comment: Postgresql is just another relational database management system.  As far as integrating it with ArcGIS you can sit SDE or Server right on top of it and use ESRI native geometry, no need for PostGIS.  You can also use SDE / Server as an interface to PostGIS, here's some information on which versions are supported:  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//015100000075000000

Comment: Are you just looking to build a web map of the locations?  If you don't have an existing ESRI installation you might look into open source web mapping options.  I don't have much experience with them, but there are a ton of questions about them here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the extension PostGIS. With PostGIS your PostgreSQL Database is able to handel spatial data and you can use all the spatial operations that will be installed automatically with PostGIS.

http://postgis.net/windows_downloads

Answer (score 0):

> install postgresql
>   using the stack builder install postgis plugin
>     the installer gives an option to create a spatial database
>     if u want to create a new one refer to this link
>     http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_tut01
>     there is also a second tutorial which u can choose to follow
>   for using java as back end.. u would obviously need pjdbc driver
>    so download the jar file for pjdbc